# need to customize features for grid and collapsible: true is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I need help that expands/collapse on clicking the '+' or '-'. Tried  collapsible: true, but it is not working..

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
...
columns: [
            { item a }
            { item b }
],
features: [{
            ftype: 'grouping',
            hideGroupedHeader: true,
            //collapsible:true;
            groupHeaderTpl: [...]
        }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the config option is (like you mentiond): 'collapsible: true', which is true by default.
(see: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-collapsible )

Example Fiddle with Grouping:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sha

Can you create a fiddle to reproduce your issue?
Did you add a groupField to your store?
Do you see any errors in your developer console?

Regards,